# My iPhone App cannot be found in the App Store

Tags: iphone

we just finished our first iPhone app. Since yesterday we have the status 'ready for sale' in iTunes connect and the release date is also the 4th of November and it is set to worldwide sale. But the app cannot be found in the app store. Also when I click on the link 'view in app store' in iTunes connect it just says 'Nothing found'.
Does anyone know if it can take any longer till the app can be found in the app store or where the problem is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application is "Ready to Sale" but not reflected on iTunes Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958646/application-is-ready-to-sale-but-not-reflected-on-itunes-store)

Answer (score 5):

It can take several hours for an app to propagate into the App Store; it should be there soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is also written in the mail you got. In the mail I got there is something written about "up to 24 hours".

Comment: I got that mail. I was just wondering because I got it at 4pm on 11/04 and it is not available by now. I think I just have to wait a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check this things :

1. Make sure to check the status of your contracts. If the contract
   status is Pending Contract, you may have to agree to the iOS and Mac
   Paid Applications contract or complete the associated bank and tax
   information for that contract.
2. Make sure the availability date provided in the Rights and Pricing
   section is prior to today's date.
3. If the date provided in the Rights and Pricing section is in the
   past, make sure you made your app available in at least one App
   Store territory.
4. If your app was scheduled to go live within the last 24 hours, the
   app may be caching on the App Store. Once the 24-hour caching
   window has passed, close and open iTunes and search for your app
   again. You can also click View in App Store on your app's App
   Details page in the Manage Your Applications module.

Hope it will guide you.