# Application is "Ready to Sale" but not reflected on iTunes Store

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes-store

I hold my application for "Developer release after approval" on iTunes Store. I have released my application and current status is "Ready to Sale". I am still not able to see the latest version on the iTunes Store. I am already waiting from last 6 Hours. Could anyone please tell me how much time Apple takes to make live the new version of the application?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party site and has no relation to software development.

Comment: Give it a day and check again.

Comment: you have to click the RELEASE NOW button, dude

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html),

Your app version will then be live on the store pending the customary processing times. The delay is due to propagating your application's status across their all iTunes servers. This process usually takes different time for different servers. But, it'll be available within a day.

Answer (score 6):

It can happen. It might take an undetermined period of time before the app actually show up in searches.Normally for my apps the time period was about half an hour to one hour although I remember one of my apps took about half a day to appear normally on the iTunes. In the initial period you might also notice that not only you cant search for it but the app does not even appear in your apps list in the iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it takes upto 24 hours.